# PromQL "outer-join"-like behaviour

Tags: prometheus, promql

Consider the metrics:

```
foo{a="a"} 1
foo{a="b"} 1
bar{a="b"} 1
bar{a="c"} 1
```

The query

```
sum by (a) (foo) + sum by (a) (bar)
```

returns

```
{a="b"} 2
```

What I would like is a query that will treat the absence of a given set of labels on the other side of the sum as 0. Essentially I need a query with the following result:

```
{a="a"} 1
{a="b"} 2
{a="c"} 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus is lacking outer join functionality. You can see very in-depth description of situation and possible workaround for `left outer join` from Brian Brazil [here](https://www.robustperception.io/left-joins-in-promql/).

Based on the same logic `full outer join` for your example will look like this:

```
sum by (a) (foo) + sum by (a) (bar) #inner join
  or sum by (a) (foo) #with first line ~left outer join
  or sum by (a) (bar) #with first line ~right outer join
```